# Bootstrap position menu top right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I am looking on how to position my top navigation on the top right.

So far I have this code:

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top ">
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
     <li><a href="">NL</a></li>
     <li><a href="">ENG</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

But I am not sure how to position it on the top right.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the `pull-right` class utility?

Comment: @Aibrean as of Bootstrap 3, navbar-right is prefered instead of pull-right (although they both seem to work most of the time).

Comment: @ShawnTaylor Yea I forgot about that one. I started off using Bootstrap when it was 2.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right way to do this according to bootstrap is using the class `navbar-right`. Have a look at this link on [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/sMmfIxo8JV).

Try the following:

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
     <li><a href="">NL</a></li>
     <li><a href="">ENG</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Update. Made a mistake and placed `navbar-right` on the div instead of the `ul`. It's fixed now. Also included bootply link.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. How Can i give this menu some more padding on the right. Without touching the other menu's?

Comment: Assuming that you mean a margin, have a look at [this](http://www.bootply.com/6JcdUSOBFM) link. You just have to add `.navbar { margin-right: 50px; }` to your css.

Comment: can you post an update in how this will work for BS4?